# Angular: Prefill wizard with config data from file

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a wizard with about a hundred form fields. These fields are prepopulated with factory settings using `FormBuilder` in the `OnInit`.

The user has also the option to upload a previously saved config using a JSON file. I can parse the file no problem, but obviously, if the user launches the wizard, the `OnInit` will overwrite it all. Short of having to maintain two wizards (with all it's validation methods etc.) how can I inject the JSON items into the wizard BEFORE the user launches it the first time? any ideas?

## **## EDIT ##**

Here's the code for reading the file and using `patchValue()` to add the data to the form. I suppose that now I need to know before the `onInit` if `parsedConfig` was filled or not:

```
file:any;
fileChanged(e) {
this.file = e.target.files[0];
}

uploadConfig(file) {

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  var parsedConfig = JSON.parse(fileReader.result)

  this.datainputForm.patchValue ({
    company: parsedConfig.company
    // add another 99 fields here
  })
 }
 fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
}
```

(my first time posting here, this Editor is killing me :-/ )

Comment: Either you manage to get hold of that JSON before the `FormBuilder` initializes the fields or you may use the [`patchValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue) method to change the value of a FormComponent. You might share the relevant parts of your code, otherwise its hard to tell which solution is better

Comment: I am getting hold of it before the `FormBuilder` and am planning to use `patchValue()`, so far so good ;-)  

...but now I need to know if the file was uploaded or not.